# No EJECT option to safely eject a portable hard drive Windows 10 system

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, eject

No EJECT option to safely eject a portable hard drive but if i connect a USB stick there is. How do i safely eject the Portable Hard Drive.

Answer (score 1):

That usually means Windows doesn't think there is any danger of loss of data from removing the device. This will be the case if you have the drive removal policy set to "Quick removal". Right-click on the drive in Disk Manager and click the Policies tab:

[image]

The other possibility is that Windows thinks the device is nonremoveable.